# EF Core: group by => InvalidOperationException

Tags: entity-framework

I'm working on kind of education project (for myself) to learn EF Core -> code first approach and I'm struggling what is wrong with my query. A have two simple entitities: article, and user and I want to group them to get an list of objects that contain list of all user with related articles.

```
        {
            var authorRowModels =
                from articles in _myContext.Articles
                join authors in _myContext.Users on articles.Author.Id equals authors.Id
                group new { articles, authors } by authors into authorWithArticles
                select new 
                {
                    AuthorFirstName = authorWithArticles.Key.FirstName,
                    AuthorLastName = authorWithArticles.Key.LastName,
                    Articles = authorWithArticles.Select(x => x.articles)
                };

            return View(authorRowModels.AsEnumerable().Select(x => new AuthorRowModel
            {
                AuthorFirstName = x.AuthorFirstName,
                AuthorLastName = x.AuthorLastName,
                Articles = x.Articles.ToList()
            }));
        }
```

but I'm getting an error:

> InvalidOperationException: The LINQ expression 'DbSet .LeftJoin( outer: DbSet, inner: a => EF.Property<Nullable>(a, "AuthorId"), outerKeySelector: u0 => EF.Property<Nullable>(u0, "Id"), innerKeySelector: (o, i) => new TransparentIdentifier<Article, User>( Outer = o, Inner = i )) .Join( outer: DbSet, inner: a => a.Inner.Id, outerKeySelector: u => u.Id, innerKeySelector: (a, u) => new TransparentIdentifier<TransparentIdentifier<Article, User>, User>( Outer = a, Inner = u )) .GroupBy( source: ti => ti.Inner, keySelector: ti => new { articles = ti.Outer.Outer, authors = ti.Inner })' could not be translated. Either rewrite the query in a form that can be translated, or switch to client evaluation explicitly by inserting a call to either AsEnumerable(), AsAsyncEnumerable(), ToList(), or ToListAsync(). See https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=2101038 for more information.

and I have no idea what EF not able to translate. Also if you have a hint how to rewrite this query in better way maybe even without grouping it'd be great :)

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Using `join` in EF LINQ is almost always the wrong solution.

With a Navigation Property this can simply be something like:

```
 var authorRowModels = from a in _myContext.Users
                       where a.Articles.Any()
                       select new
                       {
                         a.FirstName,
                         a.LastName,
                         a.Articles
                       };
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It does look like more elegant solution (i dont even need and "where" clause cause I want to display all authors). It didnt occur to me cause I dont have an "Articles" property on my "User" entity but that's an easy fix.

But still if I want (I dont want :) ) to the that using join/group by how can I do that ? As I said it's for educational purpose and I want to understand how it works and why it doesnt work that way.